# Magento 2 (Ubuntu) - Thumbnail image caching fails

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cache, product-images

I'm using Magento 2.1.0 with a bought with a template (SM Sawyer) on Ubuntu 16.04.1
Our products are being inserted/controlled by an external registration system.

After this external source adds products, their thumbnails get created correctly in /pub/media/catalog/product/...
At some point after the update of certain products, these thumbnails get mixed up in the cache: Once you click on the product you get shown the correct full image, but when shown in lists you will see another product (probably the old cached thumbnail). Once I delete the folder in which these cached images exist, it will start creating the correct thumbnails again.

I ensured the file permissions are on 777 in the media folder.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong product cache image issue in Magento 2.1.6. The following solution might help.

For individual products, try saving the product in the admin without changing anything.

For all products, try running the following command (this will take some time to complete):

```
PHP bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

Comment: I run that but the problem is not resolved

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by cleaning "Pregenerated product images files" from:

System -> Cache Management, and at the bottom click on "Flush Catalog Images Cache".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check User/Group.  Follow this URL for better understanding,

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/before/before-workspace-file-sys-owner.html